# Laravel 5.8 how to display image from storage? My Git added

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

https://github.com/Loctarogar/Admipanel-to-manage-companies/tree/master/storage/app My git.

I linked `storage` to `public` directory with

`php artisan storage:link`,

but i can't show images from there. If i use

`<img src="{{ asset ('storage/app/avatars/LOW6Fc2TBH8UoexcXLntQkzncXSDN6OsIt7KLbiG.jpeg') }}">`

image doesn't shows. What i am do wrong?

Comment: `storage:link` links `example.com/storage` to `storage/app/public`. This means `asset('storage/app/avatars/...')` would correspond to `storage/app/public/app/avatars/...`. Is your file located at `storage/app/public/app/avatars/LOW6Fc2TBH8UoexcXLntQkzncXSDN6OsIt7KLbiG.jpeg`? (i.e. two `app`s?)

Comment: My image is in the `storage/app/avatars` . I made link and in my `public` folder  created `storage` folder-link.  Neither `storage/app/public/app/avatars/` nor `storage/app/public/avatars/` works.

Comment: If you put it in `storage/app/avatars`, it's not going to be available. You need to put them in `storage/app/public` somewhere (like `storage/app/public/avatars`, perhaps). Everything outside of that specific folder is *not* accessible via the browser - not everything in your app's `storage` folder is supposed to be public data.

Comment: My project on Git. Could you take a look? https://github.com/Loctarogar/Admipanel-to-manage-companies/tree/master/storage/app

Comment: i moved it to `storage/app/public/avatars`. but when i do `<img src="{{ asset ('storage/app/public/avatars/dlGrrf8OO61RAhk18aMBu8IUbEIfF9pQaGcv9nOy.jpeg') }}">` it still doesn't work.

Comment: Again, if it's in `storage/app/public/avatars`, you need `storage/avatars` in the `asset` helper. `http://example.com/storage` points to `storage/app/public` on the server.

Comment: Thanks, now i get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That creates a symlink from `public/storage` to `storage/app/public` for you and that's all there is to it. Now any file in `/storage/app/public` can be accessed via a link like:

```
http://somedomain.com/storage/image.jpg
```

OR

One option would be to create a symbolic link between a subfolder in your storage directory and public directory.

For example

```
ln -s /path/to/laravel/storage/avatars /path/to/laravel/public/avatars
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to enter in the public folder that storage:link creates...

Change

`<img src="{{ asset ('storage/app/avatars/LOW6Fc2TBH8UoexcXLntQkzncXSDN6OsIt7KLbiG.jpeg') }}">`

to:

```
<img src="{{ asset ('storage/app/public/app/avatars/LOW6Fc2TBH8UoexcXLntQkzncXSDN6OsIt7KLbiG.jpeg')}}">
```

Comment: That doesn't work. I tried path `storage/app/public/app/avatars/` and `storage/app/public/avatars/` nothing works. But images from `public` folder work fine.

Comment: That's strange... maybe you made the storage link wrong... try to delete it and make the command again to link it...